# Prime Factorisation + prime number in C

Tags: c

Well I have been assigned to do the prime factorisation for composite numbers, but the problem is I have hard-coded it till prime numbers:2,3,5,7,11,13,19 and I want to make it general.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void prime(int flag,int num);
int main()
{
    int num, flag, i, div;
    printf("Enter your number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    flag = 1;
    prime(flag, num);
    printf("Press any key to exit.");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void prime(int flag, int num)
{
    void factor(int num, int i);
    int sq, i, square; 
    sq = abs(sqrt(num));

    if (num == 2)
          flag = 1;  
    else
        for (i = 2; i <= sq; i++)
     {
         if (num % i == 0)
         {
             flag = 0;
             break;
         }
         else
             flag = 1;
     }
    if (flag == 1)
        printf("\n%d is a prime number", num);
    else
    {
        printf("\n%d is not a prime number\n", num);
        factor(num, i);
    }
}      

void factor(int num, int i)
{
    for (i = 2; i <= num; i++)
    {
        again:
        if(num % i == 0)
       {
           num = num / i;
           printf("%d x", i);
           if (num != (2||3||5||7||11||17||19))
               goto again;              
       }   
    }
    printf("1\n\n");
}
```

P.S.:Try to make it as simpler as possible.
The problem is after dividing it with smallest prime. i.e. 2 the next step should be check the number whether it is a prime or not. If not, then factorise it but I dont know how to do it.
Plz help.
Thx in advance.

Comment: P.S.: How about you don't ask for a solution!

Comment: Its working fine, but its hard coded till 2,3,5,7,11,13,17 and 19...n  want to make it general....

Comment: I am asking for help to make it general and not asking for the whole code but just a piece of code so that I run it for any number...

Comment: it is not a good algorithmus. Try this :http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429694/Finding-prime-numbers

Comment: Curious, why the `abs()` in `sq=abs(sqrt(num));`?  Concerned that `sqrt(num))` might return a negative value?

Comment: `if (num!=2||3||5||7||11||17||19)` is like `if ((num!=2)||(3)|| ...)` and `3` is always true so it is the same as `if(1)`

Answer (score 1):

In function `factor`, first try dividing by `2` repeatedly, then try every odd number while said odd number squared is less or equal to `num`. This simple method is a bit redundant as you try and divide by composite numbers, but since you will already have removed all smaller prime factors, `num` will not be divisible by such composite numbers.  Iterating while `i * i <= num` will stop much earlier than with your current `i <= num` test.

Try and write code to implement the above algorithm and post it as an edit.

Comment: @nimish642: do you understand this answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void factor(int num);

int main(void){
    int num;

    printf("Enter positive number(more than 1): ");
    if(1 != scanf("%d", &num) || num < 2){
        printf("invalid input!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    scanf("%*[^\n]");scanf("%*c");//clear upto line end

    factor(num);

    printf("Press any key to exit...");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void factor(int num){
    int i, flag = 0;

    if(num == 2){
        printf("\n%d is a prime number\n", num);
        return ;
    }
    while(!(num & 1)){
        if(!flag)
            printf("\n%d is not a prime number\n", num);
        flag = 1;
        printf("2 x ");
        num >>= 1;
    }
    for (i = 3; i*i <= num; i += 2){
        while(num % i == 0){
            if(!flag)
                printf("\n%d is not a prime number\n", num);
            flag = 1;
            printf("%d x ", i);
            num /= i;
        }
    }
    if(!flag)
        printf("\n%d is a prime number\n", num);
    else if(num != 1)
        printf("%d x 1\n\n", num);
    else
        printf("1\n\n");
}
```

Comment: output should have been: 2x2x3x3x1 and not 2x2x9x1.

Comment: @nimish642 Thank you pointed out. It was returned to the original.

Comment: what do u mean by returned to original?

Comment: Thx.. @bluepixy. :D

Answer (score 0):

Replace line,

```
if (num!=2&& num!=3 && num!=5 && num!=7 && num!=11 && num!=17 && num!=19)
```

instead of,

```
if (num!=2||3||5||7||11||17||19)
```

Comment: Both are not same, please write simple program and check it.

Comment: second line is the same as `if (1)`

Comment: sorry bro__ if (num!=(2||3||5||7||11||17||19)) i forgot the brackets in the above code..my_bad..